# Drupal form filter

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-forms

I have created a basic Drupal form. Now i want, if for example a ingenieur student choose for a training industrial sciences than must al titles of books appear. But, if a economics student choose for a training business than must al titles of books appear only the business and not the titles of industrial sciences or others.
I think a filter would fix my problem. Have someone a link to a tutorial?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you create the form? CCK? Webform? Form API?

Comment: I created with the API Form. sorry for not indicate that. greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics, the catch-all solution would be to implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) for that specific form, that way you would most likely just switch the ID of the vocabulary/list the options are loaded from depending on the roles the user has/group the user belongs to, here is [an example](http://thedrupalblog.com/category/tags/form-alter).

However if we know more about your specifics, there may be more targeted solutions existing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try hook_form_alter. I build the Drupal form with 'API Form' the items are from a Taxonomy list. greetings!

Comment: By the way, the Drupal-specialized section of Stackoverflow (http://drupal.stackexchange.com) has open its beta a few days ago, it may be interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try heirarchical select list http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select

Comment: Problem solved! I used this tutorial: http://www.isaacsukin.com/news/2010/04/04/multi-page-forms-drupal-6 . Thanks for your comment!